# UITableViewCell with gradient not working until first reuse of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I want to add a gradient to part of a custom `UITableViewCell`. This is my gradient Code.

```
func addGradient() {
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gradientView.frame.width, height: gradientView.frame.height)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.24, blue:0.28, alpha:1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.11, blue:0.12, alpha:0.6).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}
```

This is my gradientView code.

```
func addGradientView() {
    containerView.addSubview(gradientView)

    gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    gradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: barChart.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

`addGradient()` is called in the `layoutSubiviews()` method. But the real height and width don't seem to be reflecting until the first reuse of the cell.

Comment: It seems that cell has not have it's frame yet when gradientView added. You can take view in your cell xib or storyboard and try to draw Gradient there

Comment: Don't have an xib or storyboard.

Comment: Instead of adding layer, creat new UIView subclass class and override layer property. Using this you do not need to set frame of view its automatic resize

Comment: @SPatel If you add it as an answer i would be glad to mark it accepted. It worked for me.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have updated my answer with a custom `GradientView` class approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Call your `addGradient()` from tableview's `willDisplayCell` delegate method.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell is YourCustomTableViewCell {
        (cell as! YourCustomTableViewCell).addGradient()
    }
}
```

Make sure you add the gradient once. Because of the cell reuse `addGradient()` may get called several times on the same cell. So better rename your function to `addGradientfNeeded()` and adjust its logic accordingly.

**Option 2:**

Instead of adding your gradient in `willDisplay` method, add the gradient view and the layer in the cell (once) and only update the frame of the gradient layer.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell is YourCustomTableViewCell {
        (cell as! YourCustomTableViewCell).updateGradientLayerFrame()
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

Create a `GradientView` class and add it either in the interface builder or programatically to your cell, the gradient will resize as the view's frame changes:

```
public class GradientView: UIView {
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard gradientLayer == nil else {
            gradientLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
            return
        }

        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        gradientLayer!.colors = [
            UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.24, blue:0.28, alpha:1).cgColor,
            UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.11, blue:0.12, alpha:0.6).cgColor
        ]
        gradientLayer!.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer!.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        gradientLayer!.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the frame of gradientView not set even while returning the cell in `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: Short answer: because you're using auto layout.

Comment: To dwell on my short answer, you wouldn't have a problem if you were dealing with a view and not a layer. You don't have the correct frame when `cellForRowAt` is called but your view eventually appears as expected. It's the layer that does not use constraints, thus does not "stretch" when it's view adjusts its frame.

Answer (score 2):

Your TableViewCell does not have a frame yet. You may print the frame to check that, it will be a zero frame.

Move the addGradientView method to the layoutSubView override.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    addGradient()
}
```

Edit:

I see that you have mentioned it didn't work in layoutSubView. I believe there is some problem in the way you are calling the method.
The below code works for me

```
class GradientCell: UITableViewCell {


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    print(self.frame)
    addGradient()
}

func addGradient() {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.24, blue:0.28, alpha:1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.11, blue:0.12, alpha:0.6).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}

}
```

[image]

EDIT 2:
    It would be better if you move the didMoveToWindow

Comment: Could you try it on a subview frame which has been set with autolayout?

Comment: You're adding a layer each time `layoutSubviews()` is called. If you had more cells and started scrolling up and down you'd eventually end up with completely black cells containting several sublayers.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. My bad. But that can be avoided just by having the CAGradientLayer as a class level variable. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable inside the cell.

```
private let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.colors = [UIColor.magenta.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    layer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    return layer
}()
```

Then add this gradient layer in the initialize method where you are adding UI components.

Now you have to update the frame of the gradient layer.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    updateGradientFrame()
}

private func updateGradientFrame() {
    gradientLayer.frame = // set your frame here...
}
```